# Checking the Max/Min allowed HDD temperature with smartctl (smartmontools)

Tags: temperature

When I run the `sudo smartctl -x /dev/sda | grep Min/Max` command in Terminal, it returns nothing as if I entered nothing. What's the problem and how can I get that info if that doesn't work?

Comment: Hello, post the results of only 'sudo smartclt -x /dev/sda'

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil It falsely says that the device lacks SMART capability, while I can access SMART in windows in any program like CrystalDiskInfo or HDSentinel. It also reports the current temperature as 0 degrees Celsius. So there's something wrong in Ubuntu with this drive (WD My Passport Ultra 2 TB). I also double-checked in VirtualBox and got the same results.

Comment: Did you turn it on? sudo smartctl -s on /dev/sda

Comment: @PhilippeDelteil It says "unable to fetch IEC (SMART) mode page [unsupported field in scsi command] A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.